# Preprocessor variable for armhf c++

Tags: c++

Such a question: how can I determine that the code is running on a computer that has an armhf processor?
I know that for ARM64 there is a preprocessor variable __aarch64__ and I can do something like this:

```
#if defined(__aarch64___)
...
#endif
```

Is there the same variable for armhf?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for your compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command similar to this one lists all the predefined *macros* of your compiler (of course, you have to replace `g++` by your actual compiler for the specific target, and add the specific options for this target).

```
echo | g++ -dM -E - | sort
```

You will certainly detect some explicit enough names you can test with `#if defined`.
And of course, once you have found the interesting names, you have to check the documentation in order to ensure they actually have the meaning you suppose.